# Favicon / shortcut icon - position in document?

Tags: html, dom, favicon

I'm currently working with a new system, with a few handfuls of clients on them.

I just noticed that in the first (hierarchy-wise in the body) document they can edit, the

```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://path.com/favicon.ico" />
```

is placed.

It's inside the fourth or fifth div inside the page. Well below the menu and all. Struck me as odd, but it loads perfectly.

Is this a cross browser thing, favicons being loaded no matter where in the DOM - or is it Firefox being the exception? I can't find anything else on this sadly.

Comment: have you tried to look at it on other browsers?

Comment: I have no access to any other browser right now. Firefox on Ubuntu only for today.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what browser do, but [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)  says you can use the `link` element

> Where [metadata content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#metadata-content-0) is expected.

So this could potentially also be outside of `head`. But the specification also states:

> If the `rel` attribute is used, the element is restricted to the `head` element.

So, while browser might not comply with this, you shouldn't *expect* it to work.